# Filter DataFrame rows based on groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm learning Python/Pandas with a DataFrame having the following structure:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"cus_id" : ["2370", "2370", "5100", "5100", "8450", "8450", "1630", "1630", "1630"], 
                   "cus_group" : ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B"]})

print(df)

  cus_id cus_group
0   2370         A
1   2370         A
2   5100         A
3   5100         B
4   8450         B
5   8450         B
6   1630         A
7   1630         A
8   1630         B
```

My goal is to filter the rows of the above DataFrame. Specifically, I want to keep only the rows where a customer belong to different groups. Here's my attempt:

```
print(df.drop_duplicates(subset = ["cus_id", "cus_group"], keep = False))

  cus_id cus_group
2   5100         A
3   5100         B
8   1630         B
```

Unfortunetely, this is not the exact output I'm looking for. Note that `cus_id` =  `1630` appear three times in the original DataFrame: two times in group `A` and one time in group `B`. Since it belongs to two distinct groups (`A` and `B`), I don't want to drop any of the rows for this customer. That is, the output I'm looking for is the following:

```
  cus_id cus_group
2   5100         A
3   5100         B
6   1630         A
7   1630         A
8   1630         B
```

I'm not sure what functionality I'm missing to achieve my goal. Any additional help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `Series` with same size like original DataFrame, so possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for not equal `1` rows:

```
df = df[df.groupby('cus_id')['cus_group'].transform('nunique').ne(1)]
print (df)
  cus_id cus_group
2   5100         A
3   5100         B
6   1630         A
7   1630         A
8   1630         B
```

Detail:

```
print (df.groupby('cus_id')['cus_group'].transform('nunique'))
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    1
5    1
6    2
7    2
8    2
Name: cus_group, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` and `transform` as [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) This gives unique counts as a series , then just filter with greater than 1:

```
df[df.groupby('cus_id')['cus_group'].transform('nunique')>1]
```

---

```
  cus_id cus_group
2   5100         A
3   5100         B
6   1630         A
7   1630         A
8   1630         B
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
df.groupby('cus_id').filter(lambda x: x['cus_group'].nunique()>1)
```

Output:

```
  cus_group cus_id
2         A   5100
3         B   5100
6         A   1630
7         A   1630
8         B   1630
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change your keep value to first. It would give you the desired result.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"cus_id" : ["2370", "2370", "5100", "5100", "8450", "8450", "1630", "1630", "1630"], 
                   "cus_group" : ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B"]})



print(df.drop_duplicates(subset = ["cus_id", "cus_group"], keep = "first"))
```

**EDIT**

My apologies, I misunderstood the question

You can use `group_by` to identify the same and  then use transform as `nunique` to provide the result.

Comment: This does not provide the desired output

Comment: My bad, I didn't see customer for "different" groups. I thought only removing the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

it also works with `filter`, `duplicated`, and `any`

```
df.groupby('cus_id').filter(lambda x: (~x.cus_group.duplicated(keep=False)).any())

Out[510]:
  cus_id cus_group
2  5100   A
3  5100   B
6  1630   A
7  1630   A
8  1630   B
```